# SSRS report asking for Log In Name

Tags: reporting-services

My SSRS report is asking for `Log In Name:` and `Password:` where the parameters for my report should be.  This is different from the popup box I see in other questions.  How to get rid of this and go straight into my report?  I wrote the report on Visual Studio and the SSRS version is 2008.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a database service account for the data source?

Comment: Where to set that @aduguid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, under Data Source Properties-> Use this user name and password.  Did this in SSRS report builder.